# Numpy masking in 3 channel array

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, rgb

The following Snippet will create a test image

```py
# Create 3x3x3 image
test_image = []
for i in range(9):
    if i < 6:
        image.append([255, 22, 96])
    else:
        image.append([255, 0, 0])
```

Out:

```
array([[[255,  22,  96],
        [255,  22,  96],
        [255,  22,  96]],

       [[255,  22,  96],
        [255,  22,  96],
        [255,  22,  96]],

       [[255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]]], dtype=int32)
```

My goal is to create a single-channel image of zeros BUT for every
[255,  22,  96] in test_image, I want to set the number 100 in the new single_channel image:

I tried the following:

```py
test_image = np.array(test_image)
height, width, channels = test_image.shape
single_channel_img = np.zeros(test_image.shape, dtype=int)

msk = test_image ==  [255, 22, 96] # DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED
single_channel_img[msk] = 100
```

Which does not work because the result of the masking:

```py
msk = test_image ==  [255, 22, 96]
```

returns:

```
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]]])
```

Why does the masking return True for the last 3 Pixel and how can I make sure that that comparison returns True only if all 3 Values are the same? My assumption was that the way I mask should just return True when all 3 RGB values are equal to [255, 22, 96].

Comment: Numpy doesn't know about pixels.  It's comparing the array elements one by one.  You can use `all` to reduce that.  I believe `msk.all(axis=2)` should do it.  It returns true if all of the pieces are true.

Comment: @TimRoberts this solved it for me. I reall thought that numpy is doing a comparison across the channels if I provide a list with 3 elements inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `msk` to a 3-D array using array broadcasting:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

The command `.reshape` can be used to change the dimensions of an array. Numpy will automatically fill out the "thin" dimension. So for example,comparing arrays with shapes `(n,n,3)` and`(1,1,3)` is the same as comparing each sub-array `test_image[i,j,:]` with the target `(1,1,3)`.

```
import  numpy as np

# Create 3x3x3 image
test_image = []
for i in range(9):
    if i < 6:
        test_image.append([255, 22, 96])
    else:
        test_image.append([255, 0, 0])

test_image         = np.array(test_image).reshape((3,3,3)) # test image shape needed to be fixed
single_channel_img = np.zeros(test_image.shape, dtype=int)

msk = test_image == np.array([255,22,96]).reshape((1,1,3)) # now it works
single_channel_img[msk] = 100

print(single_channel_img)
# [[[100 100 100]
#   [100 100 100]
#   [100 100 100]]
# 
#  [[100 100 100]
#   [100 100 100]
#   [100 100 100]]
# 
#  [[100   0   0]
#   [100   0   0]
#   [100   0   0]]]
```

---

PS. PyTorch also has array broadcasting, it is really useful in deep learning.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. Now I am able to encode my labels correctly for image segmentation.